# how to alias a class name in c# used in webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

My web service is returning

```
 List<Term_Tree>
```

via web method. The Term_Tree class is defined as below

```
 public class Term_Tree
{
    public string ID;
    public string Name;
    public List<Item> BroaderTerms;
    public List<Item> NarrowerTerms;

}
```

My preferred name for this class is "Term" (i.e. i want to return `List<Term>` via web method) 
but there is another class with the name "Term" and is widely used in the code. Is it possible to give this class some sort of alias to return `List<Term>`

Comment: I'd avoid doing this, specifically because you said there's already a `Term` out there which is used a lot. If you add another `Term`, even if it technically works, you're just introducing confusion. I'd rather have names I didn't like, rather than names I did like but were confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to add a `using` alias in order to distinguish, something like:

```
using Term = YourNameSpace.Term_Tree;
```

**BUT, if you use your other `Term` class in the same file, you'd have to prefix that one with it's namespace, otherwise you'd get ambiguous reference errors**

Comment: See my comment on Arran's answer.

Comment: Please try it. You will see that it _always_ refers to the existing class `Term` and never to a `Term_Tree`, provided `Term` is within scope.

Comment: @JohnWillemse Did you see I put a disclaimer at the bottom about scope?

Comment: Yes, read it carefully and read my comment again. They contradict. I'm talking about the same namespace... that's why there is some confusion (on my side at least).

Answer (score 1):

Use a using directive, something like (using a test namespace):

```
using Term = My.Very.Easy.NameSpace.Term_Tree;
```

Which would become:

```
List<Term> list = new List<Term>();
```

Comment: This will compile, but `Term` in your second code line will _not_ refer to a `Term_Tree`, since the class `Term` already exists, as the OP indicated, unless the existing class is not within scope of course.